# Solving $P(2<X^2<5)$ given PDF $f(x)$ and CDF $F(x)$ of X

Tags: probability

If it was $P(2<X<5)$ I would just use $F(5)-F(2)$.

For this case do I solve $2$ cases with

$P(\sqrt{2}<X<\sqrt{5})$ and $P(-\sqrt {5} < X < - \sqrt{2})$

My random variable is defined for all real numbers so I think this is valid, is this correct? Note my pdf has an absolute value so the CDF is defined separately for $x\le0$ and $x>0$ which also supports doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea but it is important to note that $$-\sqrt{5} < -\sqrt{2},$$ thus your second probability expression should read $$\Pr[-\sqrt{5} < X < -\sqrt{2}],$$ not the other way around--which would give zero.

Comment: So when I have found the probabilities for each case would it make more sense to add probability of the two answers.As x being positive or negative are independent events. Or just report each probability found for each case separately.

Comment: You do need to add the probabilities together; that is to say, $$\Pr[2 < X^2 < 5] = \Pr[-\sqrt{5} < X < -\sqrt{2}] + \Pr[\sqrt{2} < X < \sqrt{5}].$$  Note that this works because the intervals over which you are evaluating those probabilities are disjoint.